# Callback is not defined - Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, magento

Estou fazendo uma conexão com o magento, e a conexão funciona perfeitamente, mas quando faço a função recebo a mensagem

> 'ReferenceError: callback is not defined'

Segue o Código,

```
magento.catalogProduct.list(callback);
```

Comment: O erro ja diz tudo, a variável callback não está definida. Coloque o bloco de código relevante para podermos te ajudar.

Comment: Não tem callback no meu server.js, tenho que definir como?

Comment: @AndreNeto em vêz de `callback` passa `function(){ console.log(arguments);}`. Funciona?